# Including Bootstrap script

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

So, i have a page with a Bootstrap navbar included using PHP function

```
include_once('navbar.php');
```

and on that I have included already the Bootstrap CSS file but i need also to add the script for using dropdown menu. I tried to put it at the end of the `body` section but (I guess) because of some PHP in the middle of the page when I try to insert this code before PHP section:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot see anymore the PHP generation. Is there any idea of why this happens? I cannot find the correlation between this two things ... .

I tried to put the script in the nevbar file, but It didn't worked, I tried to put it at the beginning of the body section, after PHP includes but It didn't worked. I am curious to see the reason of this problem ... .

Comment: Please post a [mre]. It's impossible to tell what's happening from what you posted. Have you tried using View Source in the browser to see exactly what's being received?

Comment: Script tags should always be at the end of the body tag, not the start. That way you know the page has loaded. CSS at the top, JS at the bottom.

Comment: @PaulAllsopp, _always_ is a pretty strong statement, and the fact that Symfony recently did the opposite says that their is another camp at least: https://symfony.com/blog/moving-script-inside-head-and-the-defer-attribute

Comment: There has always been 2 camps on this, and it's a moot point if you have your code inside of any type of document loaded function. If not though, you need your scripts at the bottom, because browsers read the page as is, top down.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on @PaulAllsopp, I believe he probably meant in most cases, it is not mandatory but good practice to include script files at the bottom of your '' tag for few reasons,

- Faster Page Render: As scripts often takes time to load fully, it might cause the html codes below it to render slower than expected as the scripts will firstly download and fully load itself, then render rest of the body elements.
- Ensures Elements Exist: If the body is rendered before the scripts, while using those elements, script functions can identify those elements. This helps prevent JavaScript errors related to trying to interact with elements that haven't been created yet.

Now to answer the original question, check your website's rendered source code by typing "view-source:YOUR_WEBSITE_LINK_OR_PATH" or just simply press "CTRL + U" while viewing your webpage. Then, identify if the code structure is similar to the structure given below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YOUR WEBSITE</title>
    <!-- Stylesheet: Can be different from yours -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- YOUR REST OF THE HTML CODES -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts: Can be different from yours -->
    <!-- Bootstrap JS and Popper.js (optional) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is something that doesn't answer your question, please provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) So that, I could provide a solid answer catered to your specific problem.